# Outlook contextual add-in gets always activated

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in working well with classic activation read rules. I am trying to make a contextual version, which activates when a specific string exists in the body.

I changed my manifest (name of the app, new unique ID) and set these new rules :

`<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
   <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
   <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="myMatch" RegExValue="my_app_name" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
</Rule>`

The problem is that my addin gets always activated (tested with last Chrome version on Ubuntu and outlook.office.com and with Outlook Android App), whether my app name appears in the body or not. It does the same with the `xsi:type="ItemHasKnownEntity"` tested with email addresses for example. It does the same with `PropertyName="BodyAsHTML"` also. Just like the rule was never ran. Is there something else that should differ from a "classic" manifest ?

Comment: The rules should be the same. Can you supply your full manifest? How is it "always activated" if the string is not in your e-mail body? OWA will need something to highlight to activate the app? Are you sure that there isn't another extension point in your manifest that is activating?

Comment: More specifically are you trying to use the detectedentity extension point? (providing your manifest will likely answer these questions)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thanks for your answer. You can find the complete manifest [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Icxtmmq4DYIdmfTudr4qmyFMlP90-sPU/view?usp=sharing) . 'Always activated' means the button to launch the addin is visible and clickable, whether there is the regex match in the body or not. I don't get your point about extension point. There is another one, indeed, to specify what action should be done when rules are fulfilled, isn't it ? Maybe that'a the point I didn't get !

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT : indeed, i didn't use at all the `DetectedEntity` extension point. Now it works. Is it possible to launch a taskpane instead of the frame ? Another piont I was used to have a contextual addin workin on OWA app on smartphones, and even on Outlook desktop if my memory is good. Are contextual addin deprecated or will it be soon supported on other clients ? Last point : the idea was to have the addin available only when the string is detected. Now it is always available (i mean clickable), wherever the string is here or not. Any suggestion about how to manage that ?

Comment: In your manifest the MessageReadCommandSurface will always appear on all read messages. There are no rules there. If a client supports the VersionOverrides version in the manifest, then that will supercede the legacy section (where you currently have your rules). If you want an old style extension like before, in your VersionOverrides, you should either use DetectedEntity or CustomPane. For Detected Entity it will only load in a "pop up frame" not in a taskpane. CustomPane is exactly like the old style add-ins in the "Gray Bar". Eventually more clients will support DetectedEntity.

Comment: Currently only Win Outlook, and OWA support Detected Entity. If a client does not support a certain version override, it should load either older version override sections that it does support, or the legacy section. (so you can provide support for older clients that may not support newer features)

Comment: Sorry CustomPane that I mentioned above has been Deprecated. DetectedEnity is our recommended way to support "contextual" add-ins.